# Reprompt user after invalid input-c++

Tags: c++, input

I modified the original code and the first two invalid input prompts work fine. when I implement the same logic into this prompt to start a new game, my program will not recognize an invalid input, with any key entered it will start a new game.

```
void newGame()
{
    char newGameChoice = 'a';

    cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Press N to play a new game\n";
    cout << "Press X to exit\n\n";
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    cin >> newGameChoice;
    newGameChoice = toupper(newGameChoice);

    if (newGameChoice == 'N');
    {
        char userIn = 'a';
        char c = 'a';

        game(userIn, c);
    }

    while (newGameChoice != 'N' || 'X')
    {
        cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
        cout << "\n         Invalid input. Please try again.\n" << endl;
        cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        newGame();
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide shorter code sample

Comment: Not related to your question, but... did you truly intend for infinite recursion here? You get the same effect with better overall results by not having `start()` call itself, and instead putting the call to `start()` (within `main()`) in an endless loop.

Comment: @Brahim based on a different post from this OP, he's actually using Visual Studio (your point remains valid of course -- and it should be easier for him to walk through the code in that environment as well).

Comment: How can I return to main from start? If I remember correctly from C, I would simply put a return 0; and the program goes back to where it was called in main?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this:

```
    if (begin != 'B');
    {
        ...
        cin >> begin;
        begin = toupper(begin);
        start();    <------
```

You're calling `start()` again, which will read yet another value into `begin`.

Please spend more time analyzing your code before posting for help, it will help you to grow as a developer *much* more.

Comment: Help me here! I thought that calling start() again would be the simplest way to take another input. As far as I can see, this would re-initialize "begin" to 'a' and then prompt the user for a fresh input.

I just did 6 months of programming in assembly where we MUST call a function multiple times, sometimes within itself to do a simple calculation or to control user input, led ports, etc. It's also been 6 months since I've touched C and this is my first c++ program.

Comment: Calling `start()` again _will_ ask for another input -- the third one. The first was the one you (presumably intentionally, for testing) had bad. The second is shown in the code snippet I pasted, where you prompt them and read in their input, but you ignore the second input. Instead of using it, you call `start()` a second time (which will lead to the 3rd input).

Comment: So with the modified code I edited above, is this a "good practice" way to re-prompt the user for a new input?

Comment: If you apply the advice given in @Brahim's answer, then only partially. Never make a routine recursive if it doesn't have to be. As a Stack Overflow side note though -- substantially changing the content of your question like you did here is a really bad idea! Minor changes (making things more clear, providing additional information) are great but completely changing the meaning (and potentially hurting any previously posted answers) isn't.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (newGameChoice != 'N' || 'X')
```

is equivalent to

```
while (newGameChoice != 'N' || 'X' != 0)
```

Maybe what you mean is

```
while (newGameChoice != 'N' || newGameChoice != 'X')
```

Edit:
The code is wrong, it has to be rewritten, here is a suggestion:

```
void newGame()
{
  char newGameChoice = 'a';
  while (true) {
    while (true) {
      cin >> newGameChoice;
      newGameChoice = toupper(newGameChoice);
      if (newGameChoice != 'X' && newGameChoice != 'N') {
        // Wrong input print error message
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    if (newGameChoice == 'X') {
      return;
    }
    game('a', 'a');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that your `start()` method isn't designed in the most logical way. Currently when an invalid input is given, you attempt to read in another input and call `start()` again. When you called `start()` for the second time it starts back at the beginning of the `start()` method with no knowledge of the previous input.

What you should do instead is use a `while()` loop when an invalid entry is given and don't continue until a proper input is entered.

```
void start() 
{
    ...
    //Get initial user input

    while begin != 'B'
    {
      Keep getting input if wrong
    }

    game(userIn, c);
```

}